# Fisrt line of private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) always gets an error

Tags: c#, winforms

im trying delete an item on a listbox but when I press the button to delete it the first line of the code in the private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) gets an error.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();   
  }
```

here is the error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on it and figure out precisely what's null in that line.  Is it the ListBox?  Is it the SelectedItem?

Comment: I think that after you delete the item the selected index of the drop down list get's changed to the item you've just deleted

Comment: I think is is the selecteditem

Comment: how would i make a breakpoints for it?

Comment: @OrangeLight in visual studio just click on the margin to the left of the line number, that will create a breakpoint. [More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66(v=vs.71).aspx).  Also, just FYI, if you don't preface your comment with `@YYY`, I don't see that you've replied.

Comment: @YYY I cant add a breakpoints on mine.

Comment: @OrangeLight Breakpoints work great in every instance of visual studio I have ever used.  It is most likely that you are not setting them properly.  Read the link I provided and google for adding breakpoints to visual studio if you need, but this is a piece of basic functionality that you really should know about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Either `textBox1`, `listBox1`, or `listBox1.SelectedItem` is `null`.

When the exception comes up, use the **locals** and **watch** tab at the bottom of your screen to see which one it is.